# How do I route a webforms page in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, webforms

I have an MVC page that has a webforms page that it needs to render:

The virtual directory for the webforms page is:

```
http://mysite/Report/1
```

File saved:

`~/Areas/Accounts/Views/Invoices/Report.aspx?id=1`

How do I map this?

I have mapped it to controller:

```
return Redirect("~/Areas/Accounts/Views/Invoices/Report.aspx?id=1?id=" + id);
```

But I get an error.

Comment: If this is MVC then you route to a controller, not a view, and the controllers process the query string params not your views. The default routing is /Controller/Action/Params, though, so you'd need a custom route to allow /Controller/Id

Comment: George, I will be able to tell you monday

Comment: George, at the end i did implement this from root location and this works. (sorry cannot give error) also your solution will work as you posted below, so i do accept the answer, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `MapPageRoute()` method to send something to a specific page:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
 "ReportRoute",
 "Report/{id}",
 "~/Areas/Accounts/Views/Invoices/Report.aspx?id={id}"   
 );
```

Comment: +1 Better answer than mine. :) Shouldn't the regex for `id` be a string?

Comment: this might be the solution, i will try it rightaway monday morking and will let know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

From the way you put it you might not be clear on what you're doing.

1. Add a Controller (from visual studio) in this folder : `~/Areas/Accounts/Controllers/Report`

   You would probably have a method `display(int id)` in your `ReportController` class. Then by default your URl will look like:

   ```
   http://mysite/Report/display/1
   ```
2. To customize it you add this into `Global.asax.cs` :

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
   "NewRoute", // Route name
   "report/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "report", action = "display", // Parameter defaults
    id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
   ```

Comment: ASP.NET MVC can have URL Parameters and in some cases it should (like for multiple query items in a search); in his particular case it probably is because he doesn't have it mapped to a route yet.

Comment: @George sorry. yes I know that. was thinking of a better way to put it. The OP just seems confused to me the way his question is.